# Initializing multiple of the same structs with the same values in C

Tags: c, variables, structure

I made a struct with a few members and want to create multiple structure variables with the same initial member values.

My struct is the following:

```
    struct tempSens {
      float temperature;
      volatile int updateTimer;
    };
```

I want to make 2 structure variables TS1 and TS2 that both initialize their members with .temperature = 40.0 and .updateTimer = 10

I thought I could do it as shown below, but this way TS1 is initialized with both members set to 0 and TS2 with the given values 40.0 and 10 respectively.

```
    tempSens TS1, TS2 = {40.0, 10};
```

I am looking for a more efficient way than doing:

```
    tempSens TS1 = {40.0, 10};
    tempSens TS2 = {40.0, 10};
```

Is there any way to achieve this without having to give the member values to each structure variable?

Comment: It is the most efficient you can get. If you want to reduce the typing, create a macro `#define STRUCT_INIT  {40.0, 10}` and use it instead (well, in this specific case it is not even reducing the typing, but *maybe* is making it cleaner...).

Comment: What about `tempSens TS1 = {40.0, 10}, TS2 = TS1;`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I wouldn't do it TBH... Also probably won't work if the structs are global.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for your answer. This was of course just an example to explain my question. In my program I have over a hundred structure vars, so that is why it would have saved me a lot of lines. But I guess its just be a long list.

Comment: @Guapz Well, you can put these structures in array an assign them in a loop, rather than statically initializing them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is actually a good idea, I think I will go with that. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a function, you can use `tempSens TS1 = {40.0, 10}, TS2 = TS1;`.

Inside or outside a function, you can use:

```
#define TSInitializer {40.0, 10}

tempSens TS1 = TSInitializer, TS2 = TSInitializer;
```

If you use GCC or Clang and use an array, you can use GCC’s range extension for designated initializers:

```
struct tempSens Array[100] = { [0 ... 99] = {40.0, 10} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a pointer to an array of structs and give It the values you need; once is this, assign pointer to NULL and its done.

```
    int n = 100;
    // Struct array of n elements
    Struct name *PTR = &s_arr[0];

    int m = 0;
    for( ; m< n; m++)
    {
        // PTR->v1 = ... ++PTR;
    }

    PTR = NULL;
```